# ANTLR appears to be mixing up rules

Tags: antlr4

Minimal grammar to reproduce:

```
grammar GeneralSearchQuery;

id : ID;
ID : ('A'[A-Z0-9]+);

anystring: ANYSTRING;

ANYSTRING: ~[ \t\r\n"\\'():^]+;
```

The issue is with the 'anystring' rule.  If I remove any of the id/ID rules, then the strange parsing goes away.

The intent, is to match *anything* (unicode, non-unicode) except for certain characters that have meaning.

As I understand it, this is how it breaks down:

```
~       Negate the following pattern
[       Start of a matching group
        Match a literal space 
    \t  Tab character
    \r  Newline character
    \n  Newline character
    "   Double quote character
    \\  backslash character
    '   Single quote character
    (   Left parenthesis
    )   Right parenthesis
    :   Colon character
    ^   Caret character
]       End of a matching group
+       Match the preceeding one or more times
```

```
A - match
AA - no match (BAD!)
ASDF - no match (BAD!)
SDF - match
Asdf - match
```

SO it appears that any string that starts with a capital A and continues with any other capital letter, fails to parse.  it seems like it's changing the rule to be `NOT match id`.

Any ideas on what i may be missing?

Answer (score 1):

During the lexical analysis phase the input will be split into tokens according to the lexical rules in your grammar. This phase is not affected by anything that happens in the parser rules. That is, the lexer will always the same sequence of tokens for a given input, regardless of what the parser does or which types of tokens its wants.

So to see which sequence of tokens is generated for a given input, we only need to look at the lexical rules defined in your grammar, of which you have two:

```
ID : ('A'[A-Z0-9]+);
ANYSTRING: ~[ \t\r\n"\\'():^]+;
```

Now these two rules clearly overlap: anything that can be matched by `ID`, can also be matched by `ANYSTRING`. In cases like this, the maximum munch rule applies, which says:

1. If multiple rules can produce a match, the rule that produces the longer match is used
2. If multiple rules produce a match of the same length, the one that comes first in the grammar is used.

So as a result of those rules, any input that starts with an `A` and does not contain any characters that can only be matched by `ANYSTRING`, will produce an `ID` token.

If you want your `anystring` rule to match valid identifiers as well, you'll need to define it as:

```
anystring: ID | ANYSTRING;
```